# Blockchain Content

Tags: go-ethereum

I am wondering if the content (transaction) of the consortium blockchain can be visible only for the validators.
In other words, the registered users cannot read the content of the blockchain. 
Is this case possible on the consortium blockchain?

Comment: What is `the consortium blockchain`?

Comment: This can't be done with vanilla Ethereum. Have a look at Quorum (a fork of go-ethereum): https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum